# How to access localhost (xampp, phpmyadmin, etc.) from an Android device?

Tags: android, html, xampp, localhost

I want to make an application on my android device (raspberry pi), which scans an item barcode, adds it to a list, and then tallies up everything. As I have more experience with Web App Development, I figured I might be able to build the app faster this way. However, my problem is, that I am now considering how I would access the localhost database in order to pull the data linked to the corresponding barcode scanned. Should I just stick with SQLite and build an android app?

Edit: I just noticed that there's something called "PAW Server". Has anyone had any experience with using this?

Comment: Just point to the IP address. Localhost is always the IP address of that specific device.

Comment: You should be able to change your local server to host at `0.0.0.0:someport`, doing this you can check the ip of your machine with `ipconfig` for example and access your page in the android accessing `192.168.0.something:someport`.

Comment: So you guys are saying I can do all my localhost stuff (like setting up database and such), on my computer, and then access it all on the phone via the localhost server 192.168.blah.blah? :O